# I can't make an image as a background in Django

Tags: html, css, django, image, background

I want to make an image in this /static/img/background.jpg/ directory to become a background-image, but the css is not showing the background image.

I think that the problkem is in the header styles but I can't find anythging wrong in there.
#index.html

```
    <style>
      .start {
        background-image: url("{% static 'img/background.jpg' %]");
        background-color: #cccccc;
        height: 500px;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="start">

        <img src="{% static 'img/background.img' %}" alt="background">
        <h1>DO YOU WANT TO GET BETTER?</h1>
    </div>
```

#layout.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

header {

    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: black;
    padding: 28px 12%;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are typing errors `background.img`

```
<img src="{% static 'img/background.jpg' %}" alt="background">
```

and bracket `]`

```
background-image: url("{% static 'img/background.jpg' %}");
```